# Run commands on all files in a directory

Tags: python-3.x

See sample script below. I need to run this on multiple text files in a directory.  I know this is possible but I cannot seem to get the syntax right.
I believe I need to run the below as a process?

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if re.search(r"\b1000\b", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
                count1 += 1
```

Here's my failed attempt to get it to run on multiple files.

```
path = 'c:/mypath/'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    open(filename, "r")
    for line in filename:
        if re.search(r"\b1000\b", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
            count1 += 1
            print(count1)
```

Comment: `open(filename, "r")` ??? check the working example you need `with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "r") as infile:` then `for line in infile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

several issues in your attempt.

- `open` must be assigned to a file handle, you're not doing that
- `filename` is the file *name*. You have to join with path to get full file to open

for instance like this:

```
path = r'c:\mypath'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
           if re.search(r"\b1000\b", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
              count1 += 1
```

or better with an inner comprehension and `sum`

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "r") as infile:
        count1 += sum(1 for line in infile if re.search(r"\b1000\b", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

or a variant (but some people don't like it):

```
        count1 += sum(bool(re.search(r"\b1000\b", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)) for line in infile)
```