# Create separate output files

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is sample code to show that I'm running these commands again.  I'm guessing this is the wrong way to do this.

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if re.search(r"\b1000\b", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
                count1 += 1
                fh.write("{}, ".format(count1))

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if re.search(r"\b10G\b", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
                count2 += 1
                fh.write("{}, ".format(count2))
```

Comment: what is the problem here?

Comment: same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706082/run-commands-on-all-files-in-a-directory. You just pasted my answer as a new question (without even accepting it!!). What's the issue??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run commands on all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706082/run-commands-on-all-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: I need to be able to print these count values to a single .CSV file.  Each file that's opened will consume only one line in the output.  Hope this makes sense.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have understood your idea correctly. I suggest you could do the following.

```
fh = open("my.csv", "w+")
path = 'my path'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
   with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "r") as infile:
       count1 = 0
       count2 = 0

       for line in infile:
           if re.search(r"\b10G\b", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
               count1 += 1

           if re.search(r"\b10G\b", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
               count2 += 1

       # write the count value to the csv after reading the file
       fh.write("Count1: {} Count2: {}\n".format(count1, count2))

# close the file reader - otherwise there won't be any content in the csv
fh.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience.  I'm new to python.  Perhaps it's better to share my entire script to show you what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @ChuckSlayton: I see you have added more lines to your code above. If your goal is to search for a second string just add a second counter variable and an elif-statement to the code with the second regex. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: What I want to accomplish is to read the lines of each .txt file in a directory, count the values and perform arithmetic functions on them.  And each .txt will populate a single row of the .csv file.  So, if I have 30 .txt files, I will have 30 lines in the .csv file.

Comment: @ChuckSlayton: The solution above does the following.  
For each file in the directory, it reads it line by line and searches each line for the two different regular expressions. Once the whole file has been processed - the two counter values are written to a single line in the output csv file. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is working!  However, the following line does not seem to work:              elif re.search(r"\b1000\b", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE) and re.search(r"\bnotco*\b", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
                count4 += 1

Comment: Can you post some code (append your current version of your code to your post) with what is not working please? 
Use all if-statements instead of elif because there might be all values on a single line and you would want to pick up all occurrences and not just the first one.

Comment: I think this is not working because of how elif works.  I'm going to research if and elif so I understand the logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172597/discussion-between-meck-and-chuck-slayton).

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
fh = open("output.csv", "w")
for filename in os.listdir(path):
with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if re.search(r"\b10G\b", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
            count1 += 1
            fh.write("{}, ".format(count1))
```